# Bulk Insert text file with additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a table that has two columns. One column is for a row of text and the second is for the name of the text file. I am using the command below. This works fine to insert the rows of text but is there any way to also insert the file name test.txt with all the rows?

```
BULK INSERT viewFile FROM 'C:\test.txt' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR ='\n')
```

Comment: Add the file name as as second column in your text file, and add a field terminator to your command?

Comment: Bulk insert doesn't offer this functionality, I think.  You'll need to do some extra processing.  Perhaps bulk insert to a temp table and then update your main table with the data and filename as needed.

Comment: Is the second column NULL or Blank after your upload? If so, just run a simple update statement and set that column to the name of the text file WHERE NULLIF(COL2,'') IS NULL. Don't think it can be accomplished with the Bulk Insert command.